# Is there any way to debug a value inside a tensor while training on Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement my own layer on Keras with a TensorFlow backend.

Is there any way to print the value inside tensors while training?
For example, I want to print `x` and `self.kernel` in the following code:

```python
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):

        # print x
        # print self.kernel

        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `keras.backend.print_tensor`, which is just an identity transform that has the side-effect of printing the value of the tensor, and optionally a message. For example:

```
import keras.backend as K

def call(self, x):

    return K.dot(K.print_tensor(x, message='Value of x'),
                 K.print_tensor(self.kernel, 
                                message='Value of kernel'))
```

See https://keras.io/backend/#print_tensor for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [tf.print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print) when using the TensorFlow backend.

```
def call(self, x):

    tf.print(x)
    tf.print(self.kernel) 

    return K.dot(x, self.kernel)
```